# LLVM Function::getContext() - private within this context

Tags: c++, llvm

So I am writing a `FunctionPass` for LLVM, and attempting to add some call  instruction to a function.

If I make a call to `Type::getVoidTy();` like this:

```
Type::getVoidTy(F.getContext());
```

Everything compiles fine.

However if I do this:

```
llvm::LLVMContext context = F.getContext();
Type::getVoidTy(context);
```

I get the following compile error when I try and compile the pass:

```
llvm-3.2.src/include/llvm/LLVMContext.h: In member function ‘virtual bool {anonymous}::Hello::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&)’:
llvm-3.2.src/include/llvm/LLVMContext.h:93:3: error: ‘llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext(llvm::LLVMContext&)’ is private
   LLVMContext(LLVMContext&) LLVM_DELETED_FUNCTION;
   ^
llvm-3.2.src/lib/Transforms/Hello/Hello.cpp:370:48: error: within this context
       llvm::LLVMContext context = F.getContext();
                                                ^
```

So I guess this is an issue with my understanding of c++, but I don't see why the call to the accessor would work in the one case, but not the other, in the same scope..

Comment: The error is in the initialization, not the call to `getVoidTy`. Looks like `LLVMContext` is not copyable. Try `llvm::LLVMContext &context = F.getContext();` instead. (Might need a `const` too.)

Answer (score 4):

The copy ctor and copy assignment operator of `LLVMContext` are explicitly *deleted* (see [the code here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/66981fe20809820e30dc19ea37ff7487eb67a96f/include/llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h#L179)).

`Function::getContext` returns a *mutable reference* to `LLVMContext`. By assigning it in:

```
llvm::LLVMContext& context = F.getContext();
```

You're attempting to invoke a deleted constructor. You should carry `llvm::LLVMContext&` around instead.

Comment: it must be a reference I think     llvm::LLVMContext&  context = F.getContext();